# Calculations in php with if()

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to do some calculations from some data I've received from my database. I don't think I'm doing it right. Example:

```
if ($progressing > $constant && $regressing) {
    //Do something if $progressing is more than BOTH $constant and $regressing
}
```

Is this correct? I can't seem to get the correct result., so I assume I'm doing something wrong here? But I'm unable to find out what.

Comment: PHP doesn't do what you think it does: `if (($progressing > $constant) && $regressing)` What you want is: `if ($progressing > $constant && $progressing > $regressing)`

Comment: @Rizier123 Gosh that makes perfect sense! I'll try that. Put it as an answer instead of a comment and I'll set it as best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP doesn't do what you think it does here:

```
if (($progressing > $constant) && $regressing)
```

Here PHP checks first if `$progressing` is bigger than `$constant`. After that the first part(`($progressing > $constant)`) AND `$regressing` has to evaluate to TRUE, to enter the if statement.

What you want is this:

```
if ($progressing > $constant && $progressing > $regressing)
```

Which is interpreted as:

```
if (($progressing > $constant) && ($progressing > $regressing))
```

Form more information see: [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 1):

if you make a comparision and also use '&&' you need to put this in parenthesis:

```
if ( ($progressing > $constant) && ($regressing > $constant) ) {
    //Do something if $progressing is more than BOTH $constant and $regressing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using

```
 if ($progressing > max($constant, $regressing))
```

To see if progressing is larger then both of the variables